# Subgroups of the Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I am aware a subgroup $H \subset S_N$ can consist of only even permutations (i.e. taking the set of all even permutations will produce a normal subgroup), but can it consist of only odd permutations?

Comment: Is the identity (neutral element of $S_N$) an odd permutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The identity is an even permutation.

In particular, any subgroup must contain the identity, and thus has at least one even permutation.

Answer (score 7):

> Suppose $H \leq S_n$ is a subgroup. Then either every element of $H$ is even or half of the elements of $H$ are odd.

Let $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_k$ be the even elements in $H$. If this list contains every element of $H$, then every element of $H$ is even. Suppose then that $H$ contains an odd element $\sigma$. I claim that then $\sigma \sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma \sigma_k$ are all the odd elements of $H$. For if $\tau \in H$ is odd, then $\sigma^{-1} \tau \in H$ is even. Thus $\sigma^{-1} \tau = \sigma_i$ for some $i$ and $\tau = \sigma \sigma_i$. Furthermore, the list $\sigma \sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma \sigma_k$ contains no repetitions since $\sigma \sigma_s = \sigma \sigma_t$ implies $\sigma_s = \sigma_t$.

Comment: Put another way: sign is a homomorphism from $S_n$ to the two element group $\{-1,1\}$.  For any group homomorphism $\phi: G \to H$ and any $y \in \phi(G)$, multiplication by $x \in G$ takes $\phi^{-1}(e)$ to 
$\phi^{-1}(\phi(x))$, so the inverse images of all members of $\phi(G)$ have equal cardinalities.

Comment: Or $[H : H \cap A_n] = 2$ when $H$ contains an odd element, which is basically what I prove in my answer (by showing that $H - H \cap A_n$ is a coset).

Answer (score 2):

The identity element can be written as composition of two $2$-cycles of the form $\left(ab\right)\left(ab\right)=1$ (where $1$ is the identity permutation) proving that it is an even permutation. We know that every subgroup must contain the identity element so if $H$ is consisting of all odd permutations then it will miss the identity permutation,i.e., $1$. Hence, $H$ can not be  a subgroup.