# A subgroup of $S_n$ of odd order is contained in $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/518568/91177). The original questioner asserted that the Lagrange's Theorem is sufficient to solve the problem, but I think that the theorem does just say that the order of $H$ divides the order of $A_n$, but not say that $H$ is a subgroup of $A_n$...

Is my opinion correct? If not, please point out my fault. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H$ be an odd subgroup of $S_n$.

If $x \in H$, then by Lagrange theorem $ord(x) | |H|$, thus $ord(x)$ is odd. Thus by definition $x \in A_n$.

Comment: Haha......It is so simple that my question seemed to be silly.
Thanks anyway

Comment: @JeongNam-ho Not really, your confusion probably comes from the fact that you thought one needs to apply the Lagrange Theorem for $A_n$, not for $H$.

Answer (score 0):

As N.S. already pointed out every element of $H$ will have odd order. Suppose such an element $x$ has disjoint cycle decomposition into cycles of lengths $l_1,...,l_m$. The order of $x$ is their least common multiple; which is odd. So that each $l_i$ is odd. Now $x$ can be written as product of $(l_1-1)+...+(l_m-1)$ transpositions. Which is an even number. So by definition $x\in A_n$.